# In Python how do I escape a single quote within a string that will be used as a SQL statement?

Tags: python, mysql, escaping, load-data-infile, pymysql

I built a simple statement to run a `load data local infile` on a MySQL table. I'm using Python to generate the string and also run the query. So I'm using the Python package `pymysql`.

This is the line to build the string. Assume `metadata_filename` is a proper string:

> load_data_statement = """load data local infile """ + metadata_filename + """INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\'';"""

I originally had string substitution, and wanted to see if that was the issue, but it isn't. If I edit the statement above and commend out the `ENCLOSED BY` part, it is able to run, but not properly load data since I need the enclosed character

If I `print(load_data_statement)`, I get what appears to be proper SQL code, but it doesn't seem to be read by the SQL connector. This is what's printed:

> load data local infile 'filename.txt' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''';

That all appears to be correct, but the Mysql engine is not taking it. What should I edit in Python to escape the single quote or just write it properly?

Edit:

I've been running the string substitution alternative, but still getting issues: `load_data_statement = """load data local infile 'tgt_metadata_%s.txt' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\'';""" % metadata_filename`

Also tried raw strings:`load_data_statement = r"""load data local infile 'tgt_metadata_%s.txt' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\'';""" % metadata_filename`

Also tried raw strings:`load_data_statement = r"""load data local infile 'tgt_metadata_%s.txt' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\'';""" % metadata_filename`

And tried adding extra escapes: Also tried raw strings:`load_data_statement = r"""load data local infile 'tgt_metadata_%s.txt' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\\'';""" % metadata_filename`

Also tried raw strings:`load_data_statement = r"""load data local infile \'tgt_metadata_%s.txt\' INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\'';""" % metadata_filename`

The execute line is simple `cur.execute(load_data_statement)

And the error I'm getting is odd: `pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tgt_metadta_mal.txt'.txt' INTO table tgt_metadata FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','; ENC' at line 1")

I don't understand why the message starts at 'tgt_metadata_mal.txt and shows only the first 3 letters of ENCLOSED BY...

Comment: What is the error thrown by MySQL ?

Comment: @abukaj I did a misread on the SQL statement. Backslash is correctly used as an escape character.

Answer (score 4):

No need for escaping that string.

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Codes WHERE ShortCode = %s", text)`

You should use `%s` instead of your strings and then (in this case text) would be your string. This is the most secure way of protecting from `SQL Injection`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the SQL statement you print. The single quote in `'''` should be escaped: `'\''`. Your backslash escapes the quote at Python level, and not the MySQL level. Thus the Python string should end with `ENCLOSED BY '\\'';`

You may also use the raw string literal notation:
`r"""INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\'';"""`